# I changed the owner of sudo. Is it possible to change it back to root?

Tags: sudo, chown

Title says it all. I was copy-paste troubleshooting and I accidentally changed the owner of sudo from `root` to my username. No I can't `sudo` because:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

So I tried `chown root: sudo` but I was told:

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘sudo’: Operation not permitted
```

I can't `mount -o rw,remount` because:

```
mount: only root can use "--options" option
```

And obviously I can't `sudo` that last one.

Am I out of luck or is there any method by which I can get my `sudo` back?

Comment: Do you not have the existing root pw?

Comment: There is no root password.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot your system from a LiveCD/USB
2. Mount your system disk
3. Go to `/etc/shadow` on your system disk
4. Find the line, which starts with `root`
5. Replace substring from the first semi-column to the second with `$1$3HzHiOce$3cwQcLKHTqF3FcLTLAYxC0`, so the result will be something like:`root:$1$3HzHiOce$3cwQcLKHTqF3FcLTLAYxC0:16820:0:99999:7:::`
6. Delete the `/etc/securetty` file
7. Reboot your system
8. You will now be able to login as root with `Password` password